# Как получить значение из массива js

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var z=$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.ipify.org/"
    });
console.log(z)
```

отправляю запрос и получаю ответ = [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как мне получить responseText?**

Comment: `console.log(z.responseText)` вот так не пробовали?

Comment: первым делом, но в логе получаю undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В **[документации Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** написано, что данные прилетают в колбэк функцию. В зависимости от версии плагина это может быть success или complete. Либо применить метод `done` к возвращаемому jxr объекту. В итоге будет так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getvalue.php",  
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
    }
});
```

или вполне может быть так

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getvalue.php", 
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

при применении **[async/await](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)** может быть так:

```
(async function() {
    let data = await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getvalue.php"        
    });

    console.log(data); 
})();
```

Comment: 2 вариант подошел, спасибо большое.